# Low resolution drop-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have encountered this problem multiple times but still haven't found a solution to it: Whenever I use a large drop-shadow, the result looks somewhat like a compressed video.

Example: https://codepen.io/jpanter/pen/PWWQXK 
Increasing `$size` to e.g. 100px results in this very low quality looking effect: 
`filter: drop-shadow(0 0 150px #fd7000);` 
[image]

Is there some way to increase the quality of a large drop-shadow or a workaround for this?

Comment: The gradient is mathematically correct, but as you've noticed, this is visible to the eye.  (We're very sensitive to edges and changes in brightness.)  What you actually need is *dithering* to add some random noise, to make it look more natural.